# If $A\subset B$ and $\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(B)<\infty$, then $\mu^*(B\setminus A)=0$

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

I feel like this should be an easy problem, but I've been banging my head against a wall on this.

> Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $\mu^*\colon 2^X\to \left[0,\infty\right]$ an outer measure. Assume that $A\subset B\subset X$ with $\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(B)<\infty$. Then $\mu^*(B\setminus A)=0$.

Is that true? Without the assumption $\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(B)<\infty$ this is easily shown to be false, but the counterexample relies on the fact that $\infty-\infty$ is undefined. In this case, however, that is no longer possible. I've tried to prove it without getting really anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

*On my notation: $X\subset Y$ includes the case $X=Y$.*

Comment: I've tried to write $B\setminus A$ in a clever way and then use monotonicity and subadditivity, but they always end up being vacuous statements like $\mu^*(B\setminus A)\geq 0$. I don't really know how to do a $\epsilon$ proof since $\mu^*$ doesn't have a concrete definition.

Comment: What if you take $X=\{a,b\}$ and set $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0, \mu^*(\{a\})=\mu^*(\{b\})=\mu^*(X)=1$?

Comment: This result, as stated in the question, is false.

Comment: @CristoferVillani that's a neat counterexample, if you make it an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false even with the finiteness assumption. For example, take $X=\{a,b\}$, and set $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0, \mu^*(\{a\})=\mu^*(\{b\})=\mu^*(X)=1$: then $\mu^*$ is an outer measure on $X$, but $\mu^*(\{a\})=\mu^*(X)$ and $\mu^*(X\setminus \{a\})=1$.